# Double GNOME UI elements with Xinerama

Tags: debian, gnome3, xinerama

I have a Debian 7.0 system which I'm trying to set up with 3 monitors. I'm using a Quadro NVS 420 card with the latest NVidia drivers. I configured it using Xinerama and the nvidia-settings utility, and the three desktops appear just fine, but on the main one all of the GNOME UI elements are duplicated, e.g. the menu items at the top black bar all appear twice. Each menu of the duplicates is fully functional so it's not just a display issue.

I don't even know where to look for what would cause this. Here is my xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.59  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03.nvidia.com)  Wed Jun  6 22:23:02 PDT 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 3360 0
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 1680 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 2009W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 2009W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 2009W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro NVS 420"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro NVS 420"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro NVS 420"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: alex@leia-2:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout object-id-list

['menu-bar', 'clock', 'notification-area', 'user-menu', 'window-list', 'workspace-switcher', 'menu-bar-0', 'clock-0', 'notification-area-0', 'user-menu-0', 'window-list-0', 'workspace-switcher-0']

alex@leia-2:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list

['top-panel', 'bottom-panel', 'top-panel-screen1', 'bottom-panel-screen1']

So it looks like everything is duplicated. Where do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the answer is: for some reason, during the configuration, all of the UI elements were actually duplicated. Removing the duplicates with dconf-editor seems to fix it. Thanks to don_crissti for pointing me in the right direction!