# How do I remove the clock?

Tags: clock, gnome-panel, panel

In messing around with trying to add an analog clock to the panel, 
I inadvertently added a second clock. when I right click the panel applet, there is no option to remove the 2nd clock applet.
So, how can I remove it?

See photo[image]

Comment: See the comments and the answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72828/double-gnome-ui-elements-with-xinerama#comment105563_72828)